# Issues with c# FormClosed event

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running a webcam on my form. In the interests of neatness I want to terminate the stream when exiting my application. So I added this to my FormClosed event :

```
private void Mainform_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     // When the window is closed then shut down the webcam
     if (FinalVideoSource.IsRunning)
     {
         FinalVideoSource.Stop();
     }
     MessageBox.Show("Closing", "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

Everything is fine IF my webcam is running. However if the webcam is tested and found not to be running. Then my form doesn't close (I've put the messagebox in there to test if the event is even called and the message isn't displayed unless the webcam is running).

I'm guessing that something to do with having an if statement inside my form is causing the issue.

Can anyone help ?

Many thanks,
ben

Comment: Have you tried the "FormClosing" event rather than "FormClosed" ?

Comment: No, an `if` statement inside the `FormClosed` event would not cause this problem. However, this event is raised *after* the form has already closed. You might want to do you cleanup inside the `FormClosing` event, instead.

Comment: Did you check the value of 'FinalVideoSource.IsRunning' ? Is it Nullable?

Comment: @RaM If its nullable it won't be implicitly converted from `bool?` to `bool`

Comment: Are you running the program under a debugger, or externally?

Comment: I'm running it in VisualStudio Express .. so I would have thought I'd get an error message if the .Stop() method was illegal on the FinalVideoSource however nothing came up.

Comment: @V4Vendetta From this article in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384091.aspx , it appears that the compiler does not cast boo? to bool instead throws an error during compile time if the value is NULL, My initial doubt was that the value could be assigned dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should also check whether FinalVideoSource == null or not.

Comment: Good point. This is the only thing I can think of that would stall the closing of the form (ie, an Exception being thrown).

Comment: Right, but if `FinalVideoSource` was `null`, then an exception would be thrown when an attempt was made to call properties on that object. The exception would be immediately displayed on the screen when the program was run with a debugger attached, making such a problem immediately apparent.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Dev.Jaap that worked a treat. Just so I understand for the future if an event has an exception such as the videosource being uninitialised it won't tell me .. it'll just fail the event .. is that correct ?

Comment: That's what I would have thought Cody, however no exceptions were being thrown .. the event just didn't work.

Comment: @mrbencowell: Yeah, you should definitely get an exception if the debugger is attached. That happens automatically when you press F5 from Visual Studio. The only time that exceptions like this get swallowed is if you're running an application compiled as "Any CPU" or "x64" on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Indeed - it is somewhat weird you didn't get an Exception Warning. I have just tried to use an object that wasn't initialized in the _FormClosed event handler but I got a "NullReferenceException was unhandled" message (within Visual Studio) (and blocked my testapp to stop). In visual studio (Menu: Debug | Exceptions...) you can specify on the errors the compiler should break and show a warning. Maybe you're error wasn't a 'breakable' error.

Answer (score 0):

use `FormClosing Event` rather than `FormClosed Event`.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, however that made no difference. If the webcam is running then everything works fine. However if there's no webcam then the event isn't called and the form doesn't close.